# Outlook VSTO App - VB - BeforeReminderShow event not working

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

I am performing some actions on Outlook's Application_Reminder event.  After actions are done, I want to dismiss/remove the reminder (as not to run actions later unintentionally due to second reminder of appointment) with the codes below but breakpoints not hit in _BeforeReminderShow event, not fired.  Any idea on what I am missing ?

```
    Imports System.Windows.Forms
    Imports System.Windows.Interop
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text

    Public Class ThisAddIn
        Private WithEvents ObjReminders As Reminders

        Private Sub ObjReminders_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)

            For Each objRem In ObjReminders
                If objRem.Caption = "testing" Then
                    If objRem.IsVisible Then
                        objRem.Dismiss
                        Cancel = True
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next objRem
        End Sub
```

I also tried the version below after eugene's reply but it also does not reach to `BeforeReminderShow` event.

```
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private WithEvents OlRemind As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Reminders

    Private Sub OlRemind_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)
        OlRemind = Application.Reminders
        For Each objRem In OlRemind
            If objRem.Caption = "testing" Then
                If objRem.IsVisible Then
                    objRem.Dismiss
                    Cancel = True
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next objRem

    End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like VB.NET, not VB6?

Comment: Agreed! Please remove the vb6 tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the source object, declaring the reminder object is not enough. So, anywhere in the code you could run the following command:

```
Set ObjReminders = Application.Reminders
```

Your code could look in the following way:

```
' declare this object withEvents throwing all the events
Private WithEvents olRemind As Outlook.Reminders

' run somewhere to initialize the source object
Set olRemind = Application.Reminders

Private Sub olRemind_BeforeReminderShow(Cancel As Boolean)

    For Each objRem In olRemind
        If objRem.Caption = "TESTING" Then
            If objRem.IsVisible Then
                objRem.Dismiss
                Cancel = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next objRem

End Sub
```

Comment: People run this code without any problem in Outlook's vba environment but things are changing when I am trying to run this code in visual studio.  Firstly I cannot declare `olRemind As Outlook.Reminders`.  I can declare it as `olRemind As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Reminders` or  `olRemind As Reminders`.  Secondly, I cannot `Set olRemind = Application.Reminders`.  It says `let and set are no longer supported`.  Therefore I am just typing `OlRemind = Application.Reminders`.  I am adding this version also in question section.  None of these codes reaching BeforeReminderShow event.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to initialize the `olRemind` object when your addin starts up and you need to either add `Handles olRemind.BeforeReminderShow` or use `AddHandler`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-call-an-event-handler